# Hudi: Access to timeserver times out in embedded mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-hudi

I am testing Hudi 0.5.3 (supported by AWS Athena) by running it with Spark in embedded mode, i.e. with unit tests. At first, the test succeeded but now it's failing due to timeout when accessing Hudi's timeserver.

The following is based on [Hudi: Getting Started](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/quick-start-guide.html#scala-example) guide.

Spark Session setup:

```
private val spark = addSparkConfigs(SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("spark testing")
    .master("local"))
    .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    .config("spark.ui.port", "4041")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

Code which causes timeout exception:

```
    val inserts = convertToStringList(dataGen.generateInserts(10))
    var df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inserts, 2))
    df.write.format("hudi").
      options(getQuickstartWriteConfigs).
      option(PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "ts").
      option(RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "uuid").
      option(PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "partitionpath").
      option(TABLE_NAME, tableName).
      mode(Overwrite).
      save(basePath)
```

The timeout and exception throws:

```
170762 [Executor task launch worker for task 47] INFO  org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.FileSystemViewManager  - Creating remote view for basePath /var/folders/z9/_9mf84p97hz1n45b0gnpxlj40000gp/T/HudiQuickStartSpec-hudi_trips_cow2193648737745630661. Server=xxx:59520
170766 [Executor task launch worker for task 47] INFO  org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.FileSystemViewManager  - Creating InMemory based view for basePath /var/folders/z9/_9mf84p97hz1n45b0gnpxlj40000gp/T/HudiQuickStartSpec-hudi_trips_cow2193648737745630661
170769 [Executor task launch worker for task 47] INFO  org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.RemoteHoodieTableFileSystemView  - Sending request : (http://xxx:59520/v1/hoodie/view/datafiles/beforeoron/latest/?partition=americas%2Funited_states%2Fsan_francisco&maxinstant=20201221180946&basepath=%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2Fz9%2F_9mf84p97hz1n45b0gnpxlj40000gp%2FT%2FHudiQuickStartSpec-hudi_trips_cow2193648737745630661&lastinstantts=20201221180946&timelinehash=70f7aa073fa3d86033278a59cbda71c6488f4883570d826663ebb51934a25abf)
246649 [Executor task launch worker for task 47] ERROR org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.PriorityBasedFileSystemView  - Got error running preferred function. Trying secondary
org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieRemoteException: Connect to xxx:59520 [/xxx] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.RemoteHoodieTableFileSystemView.getLatestBaseFilesFromParams(RemoteHoodieTableFileSystemView.java:223)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.RemoteHoodieTableFileSystemView.getLatestBaseFilesBeforeOrOn(RemoteHoodieTableFileSystemView.java:230)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.PriorityBasedFileSystemView.execute(PriorityBasedFileSystemView.java:97)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.PriorityBasedFileSystemView.getLatestBaseFilesBeforeOrOn(PriorityBasedFileSystemView.java:134)
    at org.apache.hudi.index.bloom.HoodieBloomIndex.lambda$loadInvolvedFiles$19c2c1bb$1(HoodieBloomIndex.java:201)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:125)
```

I wasn't able to experiment with different port settings for Hudi timeserver port as I wasn't able to find the config setting that controls the port.

Any ideas why access to the timeserver times out?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be rooted in the way Hudi resolves spark driver host. It seems that although it starts and binds its web server to localhost, Hudi's client subsequently uses the IP address to make calls to the server it started.

```
5240 [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-HudiSimpleCdcSpec] INFO  io.javalin.Javalin  - Starting Javalin ...
5348 [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-HudiSimpleCdcSpec] INFO  io.javalin.Javalin  - Listening on http://localhost:59520/
...
org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieRemoteException: Connect to xxx:59520 [/xxx] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

The solution is to configure "spark.driver.host" setting explicitly. The following worked for me:

```
private val spark = addSparkConfigs(SparkSession.builder()
.appName("spark testing")
.master("local"))
.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
.config("spark.ui.port", "4041")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
```